# How can I define the parameters of a query using string values?

Tags: android, sqlite

The query below should have only returned the numbers 0 through 8. However, the result are 0 thru 87. and 88 thru 99 are not shown. The next numbers shown are 100 thru 799. 800 thru 999 are not shown. So I see a pattern here, and it is that if the first number is within the range specified it is returned.

```
 public Cursor getList(String user) {
    String zero = "0";
    String query = ("SELECT * FROM flavors WHERE inventory >= "+zero+" AND inventory <= "+user);
    return mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
```

How can I keep the expected results withing the query parameters?

Thanks for all your efforts.

**EDIT**

For anyone that are looking for an answer as I was. Here is the final working statement.
Thanks to @FAT I was able to learn more about the sql query process from the links that where provided. Googling is an art it seems. I changed my code to meet my needs as follows.

```
 public Cursor getList(String user) {
    String zero = "0";
    String query = ("SELECT * FROM flavors WHERE inventory != '' AND (cast(inventory as real)) >= " + zero + " AND (cast(inventory as real)) <= " + user);
    return mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

The "cast" was the key to getting the string to be used to compare the two numbers. I also learned that you can exclude all null items. By adding "!= '', only the items that had an entry where returned in accordance with the statement. This even works for decimal numbers such as 5.5 or .5 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't compare `String` value using `>=` or `<=`. Try using `int` value instead of `string`. For this case your column `inventory` should be `int` type.

**Try this:**

```
public Cursor getList(int user) {
    int zero = 0;
    String query = ("SELECT * FROM flavors WHERE inventory >= " + zero + " AND inventory <= " + user);
    return mDb.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you FAT!, this is the correct answer. Changing the column types to integer and variable to int returns the expected results.

Comment: Glad to know that it works. Thanks for accepting my answer. If it seems useful, i hope you will give an up-vote too :)

Comment: if the numbers are decimal, 5.5 then would I change the data types to float or decimal for the column and then convert the decimal to integer before I query?

Comment: You can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823450/greater-than-and-less-than-mysql-query-failing-with-decimal-field and http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1276352&seqNum=8

Comment: Thanks again FAT, You have been very helpful. The links you provided me helped in educating me on how a sql query works. The final method has changed to this to meet my needs. See the edit above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BETWEEN` like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM flavors WHERE inventory BETWEEN X AND Y
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this produces the same behavior as stated above.